# python - How to jump os.system() process

Tags: python, button, call, os.system

I run a Rpi W (Rbian Jessie), like a timelapse countdown system with the following script that permit to take picture every minute and sleep when a button is turned off. The program check the button each 5 seconds.

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import datetime as dt


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
os.system('sudo python /home/pi/log.py')
check = GPIO.input(17)

while check == 0: #si l'état initial du bouton = 0
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5) 

while check == 1: #si l'état initial = 1

        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (1280, 720) 
                sleep(1)
                t1 = dt.datetime.now().strftime('-%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M_%S')
                t2 = 'IMG'+ t1
                camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/%s.jpg' % t2)
                print('Captured %s' % t2)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(5)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)
        sleep(4)
        check = GPIO.input(17)
        print(check)


    while check == 0: #si l'état initial du bouton = 0
            check = GPIO.input(17)
            print(check)
            sleep(5)
```

I'm sure the script is an abomination...

But that I want to do is : call another script named log.py (monitor T° and time/min). However, the main script is stoping after the line : #os.system('sudo python /home/pi/log.py')... The script is running ok without this line.

Can someone know something about?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `log.py`?

Comment: Try creating a Python script that just calls `os.system('sudo python /home/pi/log.py')` - you'll have an easier time debugging that.

Comment: And by "*the main script is stoping*" what do you mean? Is it crashing? Hanging? Is there any error output? Is the `log.py` script running (run `ps aux` to see all running programs)?

Comment: is it looking for sudo credentials

Comment: The main script stops because it calls log.py, so it can't continue without a subprocess to do the both in parallel, sorry it wasn't very clear.. thank everyone for your answer 

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 os.system('sudo python /home/pi/log.py &')
```

The *&* forks the process.

Comment: Awesome, thank a lot  it works, I didn't know this tip!